# Excel 2016 - Remove duplicates where cell color is X, or other condition

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have a user who wants to remove duplicate rows from a spreadsheet containing 40 odd thousand rows.

It looks like Excels remove duplicates function simply retains the first instance of a value/row, then deletes all duplicates that follow.

They would like to select which duplicate to keep based on (initial preference) the colour of the cell containing the duplicate. Remove duplicates is quite basic so has no ability to do this from what I can see, and even if we could extract the cell color (I thought we could use the below):

```
=CELL("color",E2)
```

And place the color name or some other value in another cell, I don't think this could be used in conjunction with remove duplicates to achieve what they want.

Is VB the only route that will allow us to achieve this, and might anyone have any suggestions on some code to use to achieve this? Let's say for argument's sake they have cells of yellow and white, and want to remove white.

Comment: I doubt that you will find a non VBA solution if you want to delete rows by some criteria...

Comment: Suspected as much. Given I have hardly ever touched VBA, any rough suggestions on what kind of commands I might need to be considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will iterate over 'Column 1' in 'Sheet1', will find every duplicate value and will store it's address in an array. Then it will iterate the array and will check each address cell's color - if it's yellow, it will remove the duplicate.

This is exactly per your requirements (except here yellow will be removed, as it seems more strait forward to me).

For example, this data:

[image]

Will become this after the VBA run:

[image]

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_With_Color_Condition()

    Dim toDel(), i As Long
    Dim RNG As Range, Cell As Long

    'Declare and set the worksheet where your data is stored
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Finding the last row in the Column 1
    lastRow = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Set the range to the last row of data in the column
    Set RNG = Range("a1:a" & lastRow) 'set your range here

    'Iterate over the column, finding duplicates and store their address in an array
    For Cell = 1 To RNG.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountIf(RNG, RNG(Cell)) > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve toDel(i)
            toDel(i) = RNG(Cell).Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    'Iterate over the array and remove duplicates with specific color index (in this example - remove the yellow ones)
    For i = UBound(toDel) To LBound(toDel) Step -1
        If Range(toDel(i)).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            Range(toDel(i)).Cells.Value = ""
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can modify which color you want to remove the value upon, based on the ColorIndex property (To remove whites change the condition to `If Range(toDel(i)).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 2`.

Here is a good reference for [Excel ColorIndex colors](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm).

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` should be pulled outside of the for loop (slows down the code a lot). First `ReDim` the array before the loop `ReDim toDel(1 to RNG.Cells.Count)` and then remove the unnecessary slots after the loop with `ReDim Preserve toDel(1 to i-1)`.

Comment: This works perfectly! All I now need to do (which feels like it might be a bit more tricky), is delete the entire row that cell is on.

Comment: I managed to do that with the below:
RowToDel = Range(toDel(i)).Cells.Row
Rows(RowToDel).EntireRow.Delete